# Best profiler for memory-intensive application (Linux)?

Tags: c, memory, profiling

I want to profile a multi-threaded memory-intensive application and I would like to know what would be the best profiler for that before I go through the motions. I heard that Oprofile and Zoom could be good for general profiling, but what would be the best one for memory-intensive applications?

Essentially I want to see when and for what data threads halt, and how much that time represents in the overall execution.

Comment: which OS? u might have different choices under different OS

Comment: what u want to check? memory usage, or quote 'when and for what data threads halt'? you topic seems conflict with your description.